# Help restoring partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning, migration, clonezilla

I need some help. I have two partitions: one is / and the other is Home.

I have an image created with Clonezilla of my partition /.

If I want a fresh install of Ubuntu can I seth the path to my Home in the advanced options during setup? And if I do this, do I must erase the config hidden folder storage in my home partition, just to keep my file, not the actual config? I'm a new user of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition you used as /home should contain a /home folder.
And your files should be saved in a directory /home/your_name

**Yes you can** select the /home partition during the Ubuntu setup process : answer 'i want to do something else' when asked for disk partitioning and setup your diskspace manually.

Ubuntu setup will ask you for a user name and then it create the unix account and the personnal folder /home/new_username

Make sure to choose a new username : ubuntu will create a new folder /home/the_name
Your files will remain in same place /home/your_name and the new ubuntu profile in /home/new_username